# How to filter on specific rows in value counts in pandas

Tags: pandas

I've got a data frame that looks like this:

Call it ratings:

```
5                       0.607915
4                       0.118016
AwaitingInspection      0.067150
Pass                    0.065056
Exempt                  0.050218
3                       0.048180
Awaiting Inspection     0.013597
2                       0.011353
1                       0.011147
Improvement Required    0.005098
0                       0.001286
Pass and Eat Safe       0.000939
AwaitingPublication     0.000045
Awaiting Publication    0.000002
```

I want to select just the rows
numbers = ['5',"4","3","2","1","0"]

I. was trying loc with isin() but it doesn't work.

Update: is there a better way of representing the values as percentages rather than muliplying by 100 and then rounding?

Answer (score 1):

As [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) returns a `Series`, you just need to slice/reindex, assuming `s` your Series:

```
out = s[['5',"4","3","2","1","0"]]
```

Or:

```
out = s.reindex(['5',"4","3","2","1","0"], fill_value=0)
```

However, a better approach might be to pre-filter with [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) before `value_counts` (assuming `df['col']` the column of interest):

```
s = df.loc[df['col'].isin(['5',"4","3","2","1","0"]), 'col'].value_counts()
```